# DOM insertCell() different content from first and following

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using this script from W3schools to add rows and cells to a table:

JavaScript:

```
function displayResult()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='number' name='noPanels' placeholder='Np. panels' autofocus>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='topRow' value='1'>Top row";
}
```

This adds one table row with two cells at the end of my table. So far so good. But I would like the content to be different for cell2 from the first insert and the following. So the first time the content of the cell is:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='topRow[]' value='1'>Top row
```

And the following inserts contains:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='bottomRow' value='1'>Bottom row
```

Is this possible?

/Carl

Comment: What you are wanting is very possible, have you tried anything yourself to do this? One simple example would be to have a global variable that you change the value of, then in the displayResult function you check this value and set the content of cell2 to be whatever it needs to be depending on the value.

Comment: Yes you're quite correct. Setting an index value before the function, increase the value inside the function, and doing a simple if/else works just fine!